# VPN S2S/L2L between 2 ASA 5506-X

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-asa, vpn, firewall

I have a problem to create a VPN L2L between 2 ASA 5506-X (see the pictures bellow).

I configure my 2 firewall inspired by the majority of tutorials found on the NET.

I correctly place client PCs in each LAN, but when I try to ping from Site 1 to Site 2 (or vice versa) it does not work.

You can see below my firewall configuration and the network map.

Network map:
[image]

ASA0:

```
ASA Version 9.6(1)
!
hostname FW2
enable password 8Ry2YjIyt7RRXU24 encrypted
names

!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/4
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/5
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/6
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.22.7.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/7
 nameif DMZ
 security-level 50
 ip address 172.22.8.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/8
 nameif WAN
 security-level 0
 ip address 172.30.1.20 255.255.255.0
!
interface Management1/1
 management-only
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
ftp mode passive
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
object network LAN-inside
 subnet 172.22.7.0 255.255.255.0
object network LAN-remote
 subnet 172.21.7.0 255.255.255.0
access-list 1 extended permit ip 172.22.7.0 255.255.255.0 172.21.7.0 255.255.255.0
pager lines 24
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu DMZ 1500
mtu WAN 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (inside,WAN) source dynamic any interface
nat (inside,WAN) source static LAN-inside LAN-inside destination static LAN-remote LAN-remote no-proxy-arp route-lookup
router ospf 1
 network 172.22.7.0 255.255.255.0 area 2
 network 172.22.8.0 255.255.255.0 area 2
 network 172.30.1.0 255.255.255.0 area 0
 log-adj-changes
!
route WAN 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 172.30.1.1 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
http server enable
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
service sw-reset-button
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ipsec-vpn esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto map Vevey 10 match address 1
crypto map Vevey 10 set peer 172.30.1.10
crypto map Vevey 10 set ikev1 transform-set ipsec-vpn
crypto map Vevey interface inside
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ikev1 enable inside
crypto ikev1 policy 2
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
no ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh 172.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh timeout 5
ssh version 2
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0

dhcpd auto_config inside
!
ntp server 172.30.1.1
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
username admin password f3UhLvUj1QsXsuK7 encrypted privilege 15
tunnel-group 172.30.1.10 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 172.30.1.10 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect skinny
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect sip
  inspect netbios
  inspect tftp
  inspect ip-options
  inspect icmp
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
call-home reporting anonymous prompt 2
Cryptochecksum:ec1455b1dc514a6b64959311a95494c8
: end
```

ASA1:

```
ASA Version 9.6(1)
!
hostname FW1
enable password 8Ry2YjIyt7RRXU24 encrypted
names

!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/4
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/5
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/6
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.21.7.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/7
 nameif DMZ
 security-level 50
 ip address 172.21.8.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/8
 nameif WAN
 security-level 0
 ip address 172.30.1.10 255.255.255.0
!
interface Management1/1
 management-only
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
ftp mode passive
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
object network LAN-inside
 subnet 172.21.7.0 255.255.255.0
object network LAN-remote
 subnet 172.22.7.0 255.255.255.0
access-list 1 extended permit ip 172.21.7.0 255.255.255.0 172.22.7.0 255.255.255.0
pager lines 24
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu DMZ 1500
mtu WAN 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (inside,WAN) source static LAN-inside LAN-inside destination static LAN-remote LAN-remote no-proxy-arp route-lookup
router ospf 1
 network 172.21.7.0 255.255.255.0 area 1
 network 172.21.8.0 255.255.255.0 area 1
 network 172.30.1.0 255.255.255.0 area 0
 log-adj-changes
!
route WAN 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 172.30.1.1 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
http server enable
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
service sw-reset-button
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ipsec-vpn esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto map Lausanne 10 match address 1
crypto map Lausanne 10 set peer 172.30.1.20
crypto map Lausanne 10 set ikev1 transform-set ipsec-vpn
crypto map Lausanne interface inside
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ikev1 enable inside
crypto ikev1 policy 2
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
no ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh 172.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh timeout 5
ssh version 2
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0

dhcpd auto_config inside
!
ntp server 172.30.1.1
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
username admin password f3UhLvUj1QsXsuK7 encrypted privilege 15
tunnel-group 172.30.1.30 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 172.30.1.30 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect skinny
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect sip
  inspect netbios
  inspect tftp
  inspect ip-options
  inspect icmp
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
call-home reporting anonymous prompt 2
Cryptochecksum:47c8cbbb9a05fbeae874207339690a65
: end
```

Comment: Look in the firewall log to see why the tunnel is not coming up.

Comment: Are you sure you have crypto enabled on the correct interface? Didn't dig into configs too deep, but it looks like that it should be enabled on the WAN interface instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nat (inside,WAN) source dynamic any interface
nat (inside,WAN) source static LAN-inside LAN-inside destination static LAN-remote LAN-remote no-proxy-arp route-lookup
```

Try moving the first nat statement below the one for your tunnel traffic. Order matters and I think your tunnel traffic is hitting the "generic NAT to the internet" rule.

If you're using ASDM, it allows you to rearrange at will within a NAT group. Otherwise, from the CLI, you have positioning options:

```
(config)# nat (inside,WAN) ?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

configure mode commands/options:
  <1-2147483647>  Position of NAT rule within before auto section
  after-auto      Insert NAT rule after auto section
  source          Source NAT parameters
```